# Helm chart with dependent values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart that can either use an internal database or an external database. The values are mutually exclusive. If one value is true, the other value should be false.

**Is there a way to enforce mutual exclusivity so a user doesn't accidentally enable both?**

Example to use built in database (redis)

```
helm install foo --set redis.enabled=true --set corvus.enabled=false
```

Examaple to use an external database (corvus)

```
helm install foo --set redis.enabled=false --set corvus.enabled=true --set corvus.location=foobar
```

I have considered not using 2 separate values `redis.enabled` `corvus.enabled` and instead using a single value like `database` which can be set to either `internal` or `external`, however because helm conditionals in the requriements.yaml can only perform logic on a boolean, I don't believe this is possible.

```
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    version: 4.2.7
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    condition: redis.enabled,global.redis.enabled
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some Sprig templating magic in order to force the config keys to be mutually exclusive. For your case, you can add a block of the following sort to any of your Chart's templates.

```
{{- if .Values.redis.enabled }}
{{- if .Values.corvus.enabled }}
{{- fail "redis and corvus are mutually exclusive!" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

This will cause the Chart installation to fail when both config values are evaluated as true.